# How do I use the Ning API to create something like this?

Tags: php, jquery, api, ning

http://www.friendsorenemies.com/vip/blog/embedAll?pageSize=10

Just a list of the blog posts.

Here is the link to the API: http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/index.html

I'm not much of a developer. Any help would be appreciated. Or if anybody is familiar with this stuff and wants to be hired, I'd be glad to pay some money.

Comment: did you start doing something so far?

Comment: No, I haven't. I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i will from what i see you are not familiar with APIs. You access the information using `cURL` there is a good page in the documentation that gives you [examples.](http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/examples/curl/curl.html)

Now for using curl it's fairly simple in php:

```
        $url = 'https://external.ningapis.com/xn/rest/apiexample/1.0/Photo/recent?xn_pretty=true'
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        $response = curl_exec($ch); 
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        curl_close($ch);
```

Now you have all the information you need inside `$response`
Check the API documentation for the exact way to work with this API. also check [curl on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)